# How to change background image with the help of querySelector

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-selectors, background-image

i just wonder how to set the background image of a div block after using the queryselector. Below is my test. But none of this work.......Pls help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="A">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set background image</button>


</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.querySelector(".A").style.background="yellow"; //work
document.querySelector(".A").style.setProperty("backgroundImage", "url('2.jpg')")// not work
document.querySelector(".A").style.backgroundImage = "url('2.jpg')" //not work
}
</script>
```

Comment: The last (third) attempt *looks* to be correct... are you sure the image 2.jpg exists and is in the same directory as the HTML file?

Comment: Are you opposed to using jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(".A").style.background="url('2.jpg')";
```

I fully tested that code and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/eWb27/) that might help you.

There are many syntax for writing the styles which is silly and confusing. `backgroundImage` vs `background-image :`  vs `background-image,` vs `backgroundImage =>` urg... silly.

I just always use the array version below for consistency.

I also use jQuery because it solves cross browser issues and is just easier to write.

`document.querySelector(".your-selector").style.background="yellow";` 

is then the same as

`$('.your-selector').css('background', yellow');`

### HTML

```
<button class="thing01">Set background image01</button>

<button class="thing02">Set background image02</button>
```

## CSS

```
body {
    background: gray;
}
```

## jQuery

```
// on document ready... 

// for just one property... 
$('body').css('background', 'url(http://placehold.it/400x400/00ff66)');

/* This is syntax for multiple properties... note the comma on all but last and : vs , 
$('body').css({
    'background'       : 'url(http://placehold.it/400x400/00ff66)',
    'background-size'  : 'cover'
});
*/

$('.thing01').on('click', function() {
    $('body').css({
        'background' : 'url(http://placehold.it/400x400/ff0066)'
    });    
});

$('.thing02').on('click', function() {
    $('body').css({
        'background' : 'url(http://placehold.it/400x400/6600ff)'
    });    
});
```